# Apache interacting with Tomcat through mod_auth_openidc

Tags: tomcat8, apache2.4, mod-jk, mod-auth-openidc

I need to connect an Apache webserver on port 8079 with a Tomcat instance on port 8080 through mod_auth_openidc module (for a specific login). The purpose is to carry on the user identification through OpenID Connect to the webapp hosted on Tomcat with no need of further login request.

I configure OIDC according the OIDC server request (e.g. Google) and registered the client, I also enabled mod_jk. I'm not able to reach last mile. I also considered to use the PROXY/REVERSEPROXY within the virtualhost section on http.config apache file. So far this is not correcting redirecting as supposed..

Can someone provide help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following configuration to proxy a path protected by mod_auth_openidc to a backend server like Tomcat:

```
<Location "/">
  AuthType openid-connect
  Require valid-user
  ProxyPass http://tomcat:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you own provided isn't enough when the backend needs to have access to user information for authorization or data isolation.

I found a more complete way to archive it.

```
<Location "/tomcat">
    AuthType openid-connect
    Require valid-user

    RequestHeader set Authorization "Bearer %{OIDC_access_token}e"

    ProxyPass "http://tomcat:8080"
    ProxyPassReverse "http://tomcat:8080"
</Location>
```